# Strongly Typed Dataset designer resets AllowDbNull on parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, strongly-typed-dataset, dataset-designer

I'm working on updating an existing application that relies heavily on Strongly Typed Datasets.
The original developer created a lot of very similar queries on each dataset to handly any combination of parameters possible, which is a pain to update.

So I to create only a few of them but with optional parameters, so the filter is ignored if the parameter is set to null : `WHERE (@code IS NULL OR art_code = @code)` and that with most parameters.
For this to work I have to manually access and edit the `Parameters` collection in the Query properties to set `AllowDbNull` to `True` (I guess that as the column is not nullable, the designer automatically set it to `False`)

This works very well and as expected.

The problem is that the designer keeps resetting this value and there is a high risk of regression each time I edit a Dataset, even if I don't touch the query.

Is there something I can do to prevent that ?
It could be something in the way I write the query ?

C# 4.0 / Visual Studio 2012 / Sql server 2012

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's a complete pain in the arse that the designer has these foibles. I have in the past introduced bogus columns to tables or where clauses that will never work out, just to get the designer to form a different opinion

Try adding something like this to your query WHERE:

```
WHERE ((@code IS NULL OR art_code = @code) ... other clauses ...) 
OR
--non-op to change visual studio dataSet designer behaviour, do not remove
(some_other_nullable_column_with_same_type = @code AND 0=1)
```

If it doesn't work out, swap the order around so your dummy column appears first in the where.

And if *that* doesn't work out, you could write a program that inspects the dataSet xml and reverts any relevant changes, put it as part of your pre build events setting in e project so it runs every time a build is done. The app might also have to invoke the dataSet generator. How you do this I'm not sure as MSDatasetGenerator in the custom tool might not be the same thing as xsd.exe with the /dataSet param. At the very least you could quit your dataSet repair app with an error code, which halts the build and make sure an error like "dataSet repairs have been performed, right click the dataSet xx and choose run custom tool, in solution explorer" is pumped to the command line

You can also save yourself some pain by using source control, like mercurial or git and keeping your code in somewhere like bibucket. The manhours I've saved since keeping my code in a version control system is uncountable; every time you do a commit, the option of reverting changes to your dataSet will avail itself if the set has changed even if you didn't touch it, ought you'll need to recompile (rerun custom tool too probably) after you revert

Comment: Agreed.  I too hate the Data Designer and simply take the old-fashioned approach and (almost) never use it.  It's actually quite easy to do everything manually.

Comment: Oh, I don't know if I'd agree with that; typed datasets and tableadapters are fantastic and a superb way of creating a lot of reliable, secure data access code in a few minutes. Nearly everyone I catch stuffing SQL strings into a button click handler gets told to run through the data tutorials, and for the 99% use cases into work out, it's just these edge ones that cause a nuisance

Comment: I'm probably just too old.  I learnt to program in ALGOL using punch cards - these wizard things go a bit over my head :-)

Comment: That said, I'd be the first to admit that a high level design tool occasionally causes nuisances that a low level approach could avoid.. it doesn't necessarily invalidate the use cases for that tool though, and it's present as a problem in pretty much everything above machine code.. sometimes the workarounds inject a bit of fun back into coding :)

Comment: It is indeed an age thing; every coder suffers from it eventually, myself included. I look at all this dependency injected nhibernate shit in whatever latest project has landed on my desk thanks to the wunderkind who wrote it being attracted to the brighter lights of a bigger tech city and think "really? This app makes appointments and sends emails. Who envisaged that 52 csproj files in one solution, where everything is connected together by reflection, was a good idea?" .... and then you Ask a question on SO like "how to debug LINQ deferred execution more easily?" and get booed off stage

Comment: You are so right.  Unfortunately one of my customers loves nhibernate.  Every time I visit them, they have made one change or another, and it takes 2-3 hours to get my version running again.  Obviously I should count myself lucky that there's only 19 projects in their solution!

Comment: Although the project is finished, it might help other people (nice tips to add the "1=0"). What I finally did : converted the most complicated/most sensitive of them to stored procedure (that way the designer doesn't have to guess : it just takes that SP parameters) and added some unit tests to check for regressions.
We use a source control tool (TFS) and I always check changes before commiting, but I'm thinking about the future maintenance by other teams and I know by experience that most people don't check ;).